# Will these model relationships pick up the joining table automatically? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 tables:

Ones

Twos

Both have a has_many relationship towards each other in their model definition. And a third table named Ones_Twos which contains associations between both.

Is that correct for rails to pick up the associations automatically?

Edit: Or should both fields be has_and_belongs_to_many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both models should have `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Note that by convention the name of the join table will be `ones_twos` (all lower case).

Comment: I agree with you, but Rails also works fine with `has_many :through`

Comment: If the join table does not hold any other information (it is nothing but a join table), I would just use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: You are right, but what if he will want to add some extra information to join table? :)

Answer (score 0):

This relationship is called "many-to-many". And you want to set this relation throught third table. You should add `belongs_to :one` and `belongs_to :two` statement in Ones_Twos model. And it will work.

Here is some more info: [Rails relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: So I should make a model for the association table? I thought rails would recognize that automatically?

Comment: @Hopstream, no, that's not necessary! Rails *does* recognize it automatically.